# vsphere api : RemoteException while connecting a esx-i machine using vijava vsphere API

Tags: vsphere, esxi

I am getting the below exception while trying to connect a esx-i 5 machine using vijava vsphere API.

vijava is the VMware Infrastructure JAVA API.

I am using the VI Java API 5.5 Beta vijava55b20130927.

What might be the root cause of this issue.

```
java.rmi.RemoteException: VI SDK invoke exception:java.rmi.RemoteException: VI SDK invoke exception:org.dom4j.DocumentException: **Error on line 4 of document : Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "rel".** Nested exception: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "rel".|

[12:02:07:318]|[12-18-2014]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[135]|: at com.vmware.vim25.ws.WSClient.invoke(WSClient.java:131)|

[12:02:07:318]|[12-18-2014]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[135]|: at com.vmware.vim25.ws.VimStub.retrieveServiceContent(VimStub.java:1437)|

[12:02:07:318]|[12-18-2014]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[135]|: at com.vmware.vim25.mo.ServiceInstance.<init>(ServiceInstance.java:100)|

[12:02:07:318]|[12-18-2014]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[135]|: at com.vmware.vim25.mo.ServiceInstance.<init>(ServiceInstance.java:84)|
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will switch to using [YAVIJAVA](https://github.com/yavijava/yavijava) I can help.

1. The Beta version of VIJAVA has a bug where only a RemoteException is ever thrown. That bug is fixed in YAVJAVA [5.5.08-DEVELOPMENT](https://github.com/yavijava/yavijava/blob/gradle/build.gradle#L9) or newer which as of this comment is only available on github (older versions in maven have this bug)
2. YAVIJAVA includes logging via log4j and if you enable debug logging when you run the command you can even get the XML payloads that are coming and going from the server which I can use to help you trouble shoot this problem.